# Can this code cause a memory leak (Arduino)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, arduino, avr-gcc

I have a arduino project and I created this struct:

```
struct Project {
  boolean         status;
  String          name;
  struct Project* nextProject;
};
```

In my application I parse some data and create `Project` objects. To have them in a list there is a pointer to the `nextProject` in each `Project` object expect the last. This is the code where I add new projects:

```
void RssParser::addProject(boolean tempProjectStatus, String tempData) {
  if (!startProject) {
    startProject = true;

    firstProject.status      = tempProjectStatus;
    firstProject.name        = tempData;
    firstProject.nextProject = NULL;

    ptrToLastProject = &firstProject;
  } else {

    ptrToLastProject->nextProject = new Project();

    ptrToLastProject->nextProject->status      = tempProjectStatus;
    ptrToLastProject->nextProject->name        = tempData;
    ptrToLastProject->nextProject->nextProject = NULL;

    ptrToLastProject = ptrToLastProject->nextProject;
  }
}
```

`firstProject` is an private instance variable and defined in the header file like this:

```
Project firstProject;
```

So if there actually no project was added, I use `firstProject`, to add a new one, if `firstProject` is set I use the `nextProject` pointer.

Also I have a `reset()` method that deletes the pointer to the projects:

```
void RssParser::reset() { 
  delete ptrToLastProject;
  delete firstProject.nextProject;

  startProject = false;
}
```

After each parsing run I call `reset()` the problem is that the memory used is not released. If I comment out the `addProject` method there are no issues with my memory. Someone can tell me what could cause the memory leak?

Comment: Before call `reset()` may be throw exception (e.g operator `new` or any part your code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you do not need the variable `startProject` - simply initialize the `firstProject` pointer with NULL and then write your condition like this:

```
if (firstProject)
{
    // There is a project, so append the new one.
}
else
{
    // There is no project, so we need to create a new list.
}
```

The value `FALSE` is defined as 0, just as NULL. If `firstProject` is NULL the expression would look like `if (FALSE)` and continue execution inside the `else`-block.

So now your `reset`-Method needs to free the memory allocated for **all** projects, not only the last one and the second one, as your code does.

```
delete ptrToLastProject; // Free last project
delete firstProject.nextProject; // Free the project following to the first one.
```

The problems in here are:

- what if `ptrToLastProject == firstProject.nextProject`? The second `delete`-statement would free already released memory.
- `firstProject` gets never released
- the projects between the second and the last ones will never be released.

The best way to free a singly linked list is something like this:

```
Project* pProject = firstProject;
Project* pProjectToDelete;

while (pProject)  // As long as the pointer points to something (see the first comment)
{
    pProjectToDelete = pProject;
    pProject = firstProject->nextProject;
    delete pProjectToDelte;
}
```

In this implementation you are "walking" through the list, releasing the predecessing element, as long as there is an element following. If the next element is `NULL`, the last element has been released and the loop breaks.

Last but not least you need to reset the pointer to the first element (also called "anchor" in the terms of data structures):

```
firstProject = NULL;
```

this ensures that `addProject` does not try to append an project to `NULL`.

Comment: Your while loop is incorrect. In the condition, you will access the previously deleted project. Furthermore, you do not delete the first project. You need a temp variable to remember the current pointer, iterate `pProject` to the next project and then delete the project pointed at by your temp variable.

Comment: you're right, thank you... I'll fix it ;) I should read my answers twice in the future :D

Comment: deleting null is a no-op on any standard compliant C++ system, including g++-avr.

Answer (score 1):

Your `reset` function needs to iterate down the chain of projects, not just delete the first and last ones

Comment: Or make the destructor of Project delete nextProject. Be careful of long "lists" though